Shortcut for next result on pgAdmin 4 query tool
When using the "Find" tool, what is the keyboard shortcut for selecting the next result?
Most softwares, including pgAdmin 3, use "F3", for instance, instead of having to click the down arrow button.
I know I can alter shortcuts on File > Preferences > Query Tool > Shortcuts, but I could not find anything there regarding this.
I'm using pgAdmin 4 v8.10


Older releases show this Ctrl + g    Cmd + g;  Find next and Ctrl + Shift + g    Cmd + Shift + g;  Find previous But 8.10 only lists Ctrl + f  Cmd + f for Find
